# Has any Heterodyne tried the Jägerbräu?

Tags: girl-genius

For hundreds of years or longer, the Heterodynes used the Jägerbräu to produce superhuman soldiers. Now, the Bräu is hardly safe (at least a 90% fatality rate). However, we know that Sparks are heavily inclined to experiment on themselves, even lethally, with some of the strongest Sparks (Albia, the Master of Paris), showing extreme bodily modifications. It's Mad Science! And the potential benefits for survival are considerable: combat skills, immortality or longevity....

With all that, and given that the Heterodynes had many centuries to try it, has any Heterodyne attempted to take the Jägerbräu (whether or not they died horribly)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Not known at this point... but likely.**

No known member of the Heterodyne family has been mentioned to have taken the Jägerbräu.  We also don't have a full accounting of their family tree however, over the centuries they've held Mechanicsburg.

That said, it is known that -

- the Jägerbräu potion uses [water from the river Dyne](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20091102) as a key ingredient in the mix
- Agatha, at least [one ancestor](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20100419), and the very [first Heterodyne](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20091102) drank directly from the Dyne
- Agatha, at least, didn't explode, [mostly](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20100423)
- Heterodynes are keen on unsafe experiments in general but also [trying terribly unsafe things](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20070620) on themselves to get [direct experience](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20071112) (ie. more data)

... it is fairly likely that *someone* in the family tree decided the Jägerbräu would be "worth a try" at some point.